# Change of facebook meta tags according to actual page

Tags: facebook, metadata

could someone help me with my problem? I would like to change facebook meta tags according to actual page. I tried something like that but it doesn't works...

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.document.write('<meta property="og:title" content="actual page title"/>');
</script>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://foto.mrsoft.cz/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=10843&g2_serialNumber=2"/>
</head>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Facebook's crawler isn't going to run javascript. If you want a dynamic meta tag, you're going to have to use some sort of server script to do this.

Comment: And have you got some example? Or simply something, what could help me?

Comment: Edit your question. What platform are you using to create this? Do you have any server-side scripting languages available like asp or php?

Comment: Yes, I could use PHP on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable PHP for your server and capture your page's title into a variable like `$actual_page_title`.

Then echo that using a PHP statement:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $actual_page_title; ?>" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.metalforever.info%2Ffb.htm title is <?php echo 'hello'; ?> not only 'hello' but i still think that it should work by some way because here it works well http://www.metallum.cz/viewtopic.php?p=142914#p142914

Comment: Try changing your filename to fb.php. If that doesn't work, php isn't enabled or properly configured on your server. Talk to your hosting provider about what you need to do to use php.

Comment: Thank you so much. I forgot to rename "htm" to "php". Basic error .-). Now it works well. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark this question as "resolved."

Comment: Just click on the big white check mark next to the answer. It will turn green.

Comment: Ok. But one more question. I have got this code. <code><?php
$clanek = $_GET['clanek'];
include('includy/dbspojeni.php');
$ogtitle1 = mysql_query("select titulek from news where id=$clanek");
$ogtitle=mysql_result($ogtitle1, 0);
echo $ogtitle; 
 ?>
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $ogtitle;  ?>" /></code> but if you enter this adres http://test.metalforever.info/fb.php?clanek=17 $ogtitle is write on the top above the facebook button but in the textarea of facebook isn't title visible.

Comment: In facebook profil I could read this "User David likes http://test.metalforever.info/fb.php?clanek=17" instead of this "User David likes Nickelblack - Here and now"

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I see a couple of problems. You shouldn't be echoing plain text inside of your <head>. That will cause lots of browsers to choke.

Comment: If I set this url into browser http://test.metalforever.info/fb.php?clanek=17 the id of arcticle is 17 and title is "Nickelblack Here and now" it is the value of $ogtype But if i set the same url into FB debugger it send me an error to fix see here http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.metalforever.info%2Ffb.php%3Fclanek%3D17

Comment: Your code is all screwed up. Get rid of your first echo statement in your code sample above or enclose it in <title> tags.

Comment: I did it now. You could see, that the $ogtitle in <title></title> is really "Nickelblack...." My code is here <html>
<head>
<?php
$clanek = $_GET['clanek'];
include('includy/dbspojeni.php');
$ogtitle1 = mysql_query("select titulek from news where id=$clanek");
$ogtitle=mysql_result($ogtitle1, 0);
 ?>
<title><?php echo $ogtitle; ?></title> 
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $ogtitle;  ?>" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://foto.mrsoft.cz/main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=10843&g2_serialNumber=2"/>
</head>

Comment: I started debugger and it works! I have to make functionally also in iframe. For this time thank you.